# How to serve admin static files with django.contrib.staticfiles in Django 1.4 (using one Apache server)?

Tags: python, django, apache, django-templates, django-staticfiles

Django is recommending me that if I am going to only use one server (Apache) to serve both dynamic and static files, then [I should serve static files using `django.contrib.staticfiles`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/#serving-the-admin-files).

So in my `settings.py` I have loaded `django.contrib.staticfiles` to my `INSTALLED_APPS` and `django.core.context_processors.static` to my `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS`.

I noticed in the admin templates that it links to static files like this (from `index.html`):

```
{% load i18n admin_static %}

{% block extrastyle %}{{ block.super }}<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static "admin/css/dashboard.css" %}" />{% endblock %}
```

But looking at the template tag `admin_static`, it's simply a wrapper for [`static`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#static):

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.template import Library

register = Library()

if 'django.contrib.staticfiles' in settings.INSTALLED_APPS:
    from django.contrib.staticfiles.templatetags.staticfiles import static
else:
    from django.templatetags.static import static

static = register.simple_tag(static)
```

So I concluded that because every admin static file is serverd with a `admin/...` prefix, then the full path (for my case) should be

```
/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static
```

So I set that path to my `STATICFILES_DIRS` inside `settings.py`, but Apache still won't serve any static files (after restating the server). Where did I make a mistake in my logic?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Thanks Daniel Roseman for the explanation and giving me the chance to learn it on my own (and now I won't forget!) :-).

Initially I was really confused and I didn't know you had to first *collect* the static files, then tell Apache to *serve* it. I thought simply using `STATICFILES_DIRS` and including the `static` app in `settings.py` was good enough.

So here is how I did it (and please let me know if I could have done it better):

In `settings.py`

```
STATIC_ROOT = '/var/www/localhost/htdocs/mysite/static/'
STATIC_URL = '/static/' # default
```

It seems Django already know where to collect the admin files, you don't need to specify anything in `STATICFILES_DIRS` unless you need to serve your own custom files (which I don't and thus I had no prior experience with static files in Django).

Then at `/var/www/localhost/htdocs/mysite/` type `python manage.py collectstatic -l`. The `-l` means to create a symbolic link to all found static files instead of copying it over (saves some space).

Next edit the Apache config file (usually `httpd.conf`) and add the `STATIC_URL` information. My config file just for Django looks like this:

```
Alias /static/ /var/www/localhost/htdocs/mysite/static/
#In the form of...
#Alias STATIC_URL STATIC_ROOT

<Directory /var/www/localhost/htdocs/mysite/static>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Directory>

WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/localhost/htdocs/mysite/mysite/wsgi.py
WSGIPythonPath /var/www/localhost/htdocs/mysite

<Directory /var/www/localhost/htdocs/mysite/mysite>
    <Files wsgi.py>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Files>
</Directory>
```

Then restart Apache and done!

Answer (score 3):

The documentation you link to doesn't say anything at all about *serving* files with the staticfiles app. That's not what it's for: it's for collecting staticfiles into a single place to allow them to be easily served by Apache. (It does deal with serving files in development, but that's not what we're talking about here.)

You still need to set up Apache to serve the files from the relevant location via the static/ prefix.

Comment: I have Apache set up already to deploy Django with `mod_wsgi` and using `wsgi.py` that's included in Django 1.4. I followed the [documentation's suggestion](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/).

Comment: So? You still need to set it up to serve your static files, as explained further down that page.

Comment: Then I'm confused. Do I need to go to `/var/www/localhost/htdocs/` and create a `static` symbolic link to `/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static` or something?

Comment: I thought using `django.contrib.staticfiles` was 1 of the 4 available options? The other 3 options are "Create a symbolic link...", "Use an Alias directive...", and "Copy the admin static files...".

Comment: No, "using staticfiles" in that section is explained as "using the collectstatic management command to collect the static files in STATIC_ROOT, and then configuring your Web server to serve STATIC_ROOT at STATIC_URL".

Comment: A case of suboptimal wording; "handle" doesn't mean "serve", in this case. A better word for them to use would be "manage". (File a bug about it.)